# pymongo use string to query instead of dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way in pymongo to use a string to execute a query instead of a dictionary?
I would like to be able to use exactly the same syntax as on MongoDB shell from python/pymongo. Is that possible?

Comment: What kind of syntax are you looking for? You could probably define a helper function that does this for you. It's common for me, for example, to create a function like `def find(s): return mongo.db.col.findOne({"_id": s})`

Comment: yes but that's not what I was looking for.  The poc i'm working is needs to execute whatever query provided by a user.  I want to leave all the real work up to the mongodb server itself.

Comment: That does not sound like a very good idea. You understand a crafty user would be able to read and write whatever they want to your database?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB shell is full-featured javascript console/interpreter with some bindings to message with a mongodb server. In contrast PyMongo lacks embedded javascript interpreter or even javascript parser so you could not execute MongoDB shell queries as-is.

Note that mongo shell queries are not json documents as they are able to contain some functions and some object constructors such as `{value: 2+2}`.

Comment: Yes, you're right that puts everything into context.  Then what I'm looking for is a way to execute javascript code through pymongo.  I'll have a look at mjhm's proposal of eval()

Answer (score 1):

The [`eval()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.eval) function might be what you're looking for.  Note that it executes the JS code on the db server -- NOT in a Mongo shell on some client.  Therefore it comes with lots of warnings, and I would strongly advise against using it in a serious production situation.  See the [Mongo db.eval docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval) for details and examples.

Comment: That might indeed be what I'm looking for.  I'm going to do some testing and let you know the outcome.

Comment: That wont be efficient - I'd recommend using the idiomatic python that pymongo gives you.  It will be more efficient and is native python, which maps closely to the native shell.